# Randomly generating a matrix in Golang

Tags: matrix, go, random

I'm currently writing a program and I want to randomly generate a matrix.

Currently I'm pre-setting the values in it as follows:

```
    m1 := [3][3]int{
    [3]int{1, 1, 1},
    [3]int{4, 1, 7},
    [3]int{1, 65, 1},
}
```

However I want the values inputted to be randomly generated in a range from 1-100.

```
import "math/rand"
```

I am importing the above library and trying to utilise it.

I have attempted to get this working however can't seem to make any headway.

```
    m1 := [3][3]int{
    [3]int{rand.Intn, 1, 1},
    [3]int{4, 1, 7},
    [3]int{1, 65, 1},
}
```

I have attempted to complete it with the above solution to make the first number random however I get the following error.

```
cannot use rand.Intn (type func(int) int) as type int in array or slice literal
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer is the fact that `rand.Intn()` generates a random integer between 0 and `n`, where `n` is a parameter to this method. The error that you are getting is the compiler complaining that you are trying to initialize an `int` value with a function that requires two `int`s and returns one - you are trying to assign a function to an `int`.  So the correct call would be something like `rand.Intn(100)`, which will give you a random number between 0 - 100.

However, why do it this way? Why not dynamically initialize your array with random numbers as:

```
m1 := [3][3]int{}
for i:=0; i<3; i++ {
    for j:=0; j<3; j++ {
        m1[i][j] = rand.Int()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is answered above, this is an extension,

While `rand.Int(10)` always gives you 1, as it isn't seeded,
you can add this function to get random values each time you run your program,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
//we are seeding the rand variable with present time 
//so that we would get different output each time
}

func main() {
    randMatrix := make([][]int, 3) 
// we have created a slice with length 3 
//which can hold type []int, these can be of different length
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        randMatrix[i] = make([]int, 3) 
// we are creating a slice which can hold type int
    }
    generate(randMatrix)
    fmt.Println(randMatrix)
}

func generate(randMatrix [][]int) {
    for i, innerArray := range randMatrix {
        for j := range innerArray {
            randMatrix[i][j] = rand.Intn(100)
//looping over each element of array and assigning it a random variable
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates random Matrix, below 100, while you can also use flags for any kind of future use and generalize the values,

```
import  "flag"

var outerDim, innerDim, limit *int

func main() {
    outerDim = flag.Int("outerDim", 3, "Outer dimension of the matrix")
    innerDim = flag.Int("innerDim", 3, "inner dimenstion of the matrix")
    limit = flag.Int("limit", 100, "matrix values are limited specified value")
    flag.Parse()
    randMatrix := make([][]int, *outerDim)
    for i := 0; i < *outerDim; i++ {
        randMatrix[i] = make([]int, *innerDim)
    }
    generate(randMatrix)
    printMatrix(randMatrix)
}

func generate(randMatrix [][]int) {
    for i, innerArray := range randMatrix {
        for j := range innerArray {
            randMatrix[i][j] = rand.Intn(*limit)
        }
    }
}

func printMatrix(randMatrix [][]int) {
//looping over 2D slice and extracting 1D slice to val
    for _, val := range randMatrix {
        fmt.Println(val)// printing each slice
    }
}
```

We could modify the printMatrix function above, by looping over each integer and then formatting it well by using `fmt.Printf()`, but that would complicate things when we don't known the length of the limit...